# How can I add a private key to a certificate in the windows trust store in c++?

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, private-key

I have a file with a certificate in it, and I have a file with a private key file in it.

if I run this command

certutil –MergePFX certfile.cer certfile.pfx

I get a pfx file that if I run with explorer, it runs the windows certificate import wizard. If I run through the wizard, I end up with the cert with the key in the windows trust store. Exactly what I need.

I'm trying to do this programatically.

The problem seems to be in the CertAddCertificateContextToStore function.
In the remarks it says:

> The certificate context is not duplicated using CertDuplicateCertificateContext. Instead, the function creates a new copy of the context and adds it to the store. In addition to the encoded certificate, CertDuplicateCertificateContext also copies the context's properties, with the exception of the CERT_KEY_PROV_HANDLE_PROP_ID and CERT_KEY_CONTEXT_PROP_ID properties.

So certduplicatecertificatecontext very specifically will not copy the private key, and it seems that CertAddCertificateContextToStore doesn't either.

I have a HCRYPTPROV struct with my private key and I use CERT_KEY_CONTEXT_PROP_ID and CERT_KEY_PROV_HANDLE_PROP_ID (I tried them both) to CertSetCertificateContextProperty my certificate context, and then I store it in the windows trust store with CertAddCertificateContextToStore. And no matter what I try, the certificate goes in without the private key.

I'm verifying this with the certmgr tool that shows if a private key is attached, and I can also see it not work when I use that client certificate in a curl request I'm making.

Another thing I tried was this:

The last parameter to CertAddCertificateContextToStore is the handle to the copy of the context that is made. I figure the original context is the one I created where I read the certificate in from disk. This new certificate is the one tied to the actual on-disk store that certmgr reads.

So after I call CertAddCertificateContextToStore, I take the new cert and I add the private key, again via CertSetCertificateContextProperty, and then for good measure, I call CertControlStore to push the in-memory version of the context to disk. Still no effect. Every function call succeeds, but the private key never makes it to the windows trust store.

So in short, my question is what is the windows certificate import tool doing that I am not that will allow me to store a private key along with the certificate in the windows trust store?

I've found a handful of other questions and program examples and message boards dating back to 2002 and none are very explicit, and none of the code examples do exactly what I need, but I know I have all the pieces, they just don't yield the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly believe that you set incorrect properties. You should set only `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` context property in the `CertSetCertificateContextProperty` call to associate certificate with private key.

If you have a HCRYPTPROV handle, then you have all necessary information to construct `CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO` structure.

Comment: so yeah, I discovered that last night, this is the first time I've managed to affect change in the windows trust store after the cert was written there. So now I call CertSetCertificateContextProperty(newcert, CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, 0, &ckp); and I get a little key in the icon in certmgr.  When I look at the certificate  it says "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate". But if I try and export the certificate it says "Note the associated private key cannot be found. Only the certificate can be exported." The private key is not there. How do I tell what I did wrong?

Comment: got it to work, thanks for the confirmation, I had to line up the key context better.